# Back button restarts activity in stead of going back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

I have a bug in my application I can't figure out. There are three activities: HomeActivity - `A`, TestActivity - `B` and ResultActivity - `C`.

Activity `A` launches `B` in a normal way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then activity `B` launches `C` in the same way. When `C` is done it goes back to `A` clearing the stack like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now the process can be repeated ad infinitum, without any issues. However, I have a shortcut that lets the user start `B` from `C` via `A` by sending a parameter to `A` `intent.putExtra("startTest", true);` which `A` uses to start `B`. Now what happens is if I press the back button, being in activity `B`, the activity gets restarted in stead of going back to `A`.

The activity stack seems to be just fine according to `adb shell dumpsys activity`:

```
Activity stack:
* TaskRecord{408276f0 #60 A com.company.app}
clearOnBackground=false numActivities=3 rootWasReset=true
affinity=com.company.app
intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.app/.LoginActivity bnds=[120,241][240,391]}
realActivity=com.company.app/.LoginActivity
lastActiveTime=756688148 (inactive for 6s)
* Hist #12: HistoryRecord{40ab2248 com.company.app/.TestActivity}
    packageName=com.company.app processName=com.company.app
    launchedFromUid=10109 app=ProcessRecord{4089aed0 16527:com.company.app/10109}
    Intent { cmp=com.company.app/.TestActivity }
    frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{408276f0 #60 A com.company.app}
    taskAffinity=com.company.app
    realActivity=com.company.app/.TestActivity
    base=/data/app/com.company.app-1.apk/data/app/com.company.app-1.apk data=/data/data/com.company.app
    labelRes=0x0 icon=0x7f02000b theme=0x103000d
    stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true isHomeActivity=false
    configuration={ scale=1.0 imsi=242/1 loc=nb_NO touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=22}
    launchFailed=false haveState=false icicle=null
    state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
    keysPaused=false inHistory=true launchMode=0
    fullscreen=true visible=true frozenBeforeDestroy=false thumbnailNeeded=false idle=true
    waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true
* Hist #11: HistoryRecord{40a548e8 com.company.app/.HomeActivity}
    packageName=com.company.app processName=com.company.app
    launchedFromUid=10109 app=ProcessRecord{4089aed0 16527:com.company.app/10109}
    Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.company.app/.HomeActivity }
    frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{408276f0 #60 A com.company.app}
    taskAffinity=com.company.app
    realActivity=com.company.app/.HomeActivity
    base=/data/app/com.company.app-1.apk/data/app/com.company.app-1.apk data=/data/data/com.company.app
    labelRes=0x0 icon=0x7f02000b theme=0x103000d
    stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true isHomeActivity=false
    configuration={ scale=1.0 imsi=242/1 loc=nb_NO touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=22}
    launchFailed=false haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1192]
    state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
    keysPaused=false inHistory=true launchMode=0
    fullscreen=true visible=false frozenBeforeDestroy=false thumbnailNeeded=false idle=true
```

It doesn't matter how many times I press the back button. The stack remains the same, and activity `B` keeps on restarting.

Now to the even stranger part: If i double tap the back button, it does indeed traverse back into the stack giving me activity `A`.

I don't have any special handeling of the back button, and since it works well i case 1 but not case 2 I'm really lost. Searching hasen't really got me anything, so any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here are what I think are the relevant bits from the activities

- [HomeActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/tpmrEiZz)
- [TestActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/6uTH4WA0)
- [ResultActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/22D49yBC)

Comment: Can you post your some of code snippet for All three Activity?

Comment: Yes, please post more code, especially related to implementation of "shortcut that lets the user start B from C via A by sending a parameter to A".

Comment: Added some code. Pay attention to `doStartTest()` in ResultActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you made normal scenario Complex. If You have use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` with **necessary Flags and Conditions** in your Activities then Above problems never occurs..

**Reason:**

As I have doubt when you press Back Button from B Activity its call repeatedly `protected void onBackendStarted()` of **HomeActivity** And your Activity B keep Restarting..

**Update:**

You have to remove **startTest** from Intent Once Activity B is started. So next Time it will not Launch Repeatedly.

**Something like:**

`getIntent().removeExtra("startTest");` to `onBackendStarted()`.

Comment: As I have doubt when you press Back Button from B Activity its call repeatedly  `protected void onBackendStarted()` of HomeActivity And your Activity B keep Restarting..

Comment: That actually worked! By adding  `getIntent().removeExtra("startTest");` to `onBackendStarted()` in HomeActivity it broke the loop. If you edit your answer accordingly, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.gc();
        Intent I = new Intent(EditProfile.this, SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(I);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: In which activity? And is it the `System.gc()` part? `super.onBackPressed()` already calls `finish()`, so that part shouldn't be necessary.